# Bernoulli trials HELP

Tags: probability

Assume that a box contains 3 defective widgets and 8 acceptable widgets. There are 3 inspectors, each of whom selects a widget from the box at random, inspects it, and then replaces it in the box. Each inspector makes his or her inspection at a different time.
What is the probability that at least one inspector will find a defective widget?

Currently I have an answer of (819/1331), however it's wrong. I got this answer by making the Pr[success] = choosing defective widget, p = (3/11), and n = 3.

Therefore, I did 1 - Pr[0 success] --> 1 - (3C0 * (3/11)^0 * (8/11)^3)

Can anyone explain why it's wrong and how to get the right answer?

Comment: Number $X$ of inspectors finding defectives has $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(3, 3/11).$ You seek $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 1 - (8/11)^3.$

Answer (score 1):

The probability for at least one success among the three tries is indeed: $1-{}^3\mathrm C_0 {(\frac{3}{11})}^{0}{(\frac{8}{11})}^{3} = \dfrac{819}{1331}$

What makes you think it is not?   You are correctly modelling the count of defective widgets as a Binomial Random Variable with success rate $3/11$ and trial amount $3$.